# join on subquery results

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I've got a table called `IssueStatuses` and another table called Issues.  Issues has a `StatusID` and `SubStatusID`, both of which are from the `IssueStatuses` table which has an additional field that states if it's a `SubStatus` or not, like so:

**IssueStatuses**

- IssueStatusID
- IssueStatus
- IsSubStatus

I'm trying to get a list of `SubStatuses` for a particular list of Issues.  In SQL it's:

```
SELECT iss.IssueStatus, COUNT(iss.IssueStatus) AS Total
FROM Issues AS Issues 
INNER JOIN Rooms r ON Issues.RoomID = r.RoomID 
INNER JOIN Locations l ON l.LocationID = r.LocationID 
INNER JOIN Customers c ON l.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM IssueStatuses WHERE IsSubStatus = 0) ist ON Issues.IssueStatusID = ist.IssueStatusID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM IssueStatuses WHERE IsSubStatus = 1) iss ON Issues.IssueSubStatusID = iss.IssueStatusID 
WHERE c.Customer = 'ABC' 
AND l.Location = 'MySite'
GROUP BY iss.IssueStatus
```

but I"m having trouble converting it to LINQ.  The desired output would be something like:

```
IssueStatus | Total
-------------------
Open          15
Delayed       25
On Time       8
```

Here's what I've tried with LINQ:

```
var query = from i in Issues
join r in Rooms on i.RoomID equals r.RoomID
join l in Locations on r.RoomID equals l.LocationID
join c in Customers on l.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
where i.IssueStatusID == (from ist in IssueStatuses
                            where ist.IsSubStatus == false
                            select ist)
&& i.IssueSubStatusID == (from iss in IssueStatuses
                            where iss.IsSubStatus == true
                            select iss)
&& c.Custome == "ABC"
&& l.Location == "MySite"
    group i by i.IssueStatus
```

but I know it's wrong because `LINQPad` throws an error stating:

```
can't convert int to type Models.IssueStatus
```

What I need to do is use `iss.IssueStaus` to group on but I can't access it.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (untested but I should be close):

```
var query = from i in Issues
            join r in Rooms on i.RoomID equals r.RoomID
            join l in Locations on r.LocationID equals l.LocationID
            join c in Customers on l.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
            join ist in IssueStatuses on i.IssueStatusID equals ist.IssueStatusID
            join iss in IssueStatuses on i.IssueSubStatusID equals iss.IssueStatusID
            where !ist.IsSubStatus && iss.IsSubStatus
                && c.Customer == "ABC"
                && l.Location == "MySite"
            group i by iss.IssueStatus into g
            select new {IssueStatus = g.Key, Total = g.Count()}
```

Comment: @Robert Odd. What if you just do a select instead of the group by for now, do you get the records you would expect?

Comment: Disregard, I had a bad join on Rooms and Locations. join l in Locations on r.RoomID equals l.LocationID should have been r.LocationID equals l.LocationID.  After fixing that, it works as expected!

Comment: @Robert Yes you did. I just copied your code, sorry. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Your two inner `from` statements return objects and not IDs ... select the ID you need like `ist.IssueStatusID`:

```
var query = from i in Issues
join r in Rooms on i.RoomID equals r.RoomID
join l in Locations on r.RoomID equals l.LocationID
join c in Customers on l.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
where (from ist in IssueStatuses
                            where ist.IsSubStatus == false
                            select ist.IssueStatusID).Contains(i.IssusStatusID)
&& (from iss in IssueStatuses
                            where iss.IsSubStatus == true
                            select iss.IssueStatusID).Contains(i.IssueSubStatusID)
&& c.Customer == "ABC"
&& l.Location == "MySite"
    group i by i.IssueStatus
```

Comment: Well, I solved his first error ... fixed - changed to contains